# Drop columns if all of their values in a specific date range are NaNs using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a data sample as follows:

```
          date  value1    value2    value3
0   2021-10-12   1.015  1.115668  1.015000
1   2021-10-13     NaN  1.104622  1.030225
2   2021-10-14     NaN  1.093685       NaN
3   2021-10-15   1.015  1.082857       NaN
4   2021-10-16   1.015  1.072135  1.077284
5   2021-10-29   1.015  1.061520  1.093443
6   2021-10-30   1.015  1.051010  1.109845
7   2021-10-31   1.015       NaN  1.126493
8    2021-11-1   1.015       NaN       NaN
9    2021-11-2   1.015  1.020100       NaN
10   2021-11-3     NaN  1.010000       NaN
11  2021-11-30   1.015  1.000000       NaN
```

Let's say I want to drop columns whose values **all are `NaN`s** in the November of 2021, which means range of `2021-11-01` to `2021-11-30` (including the starting and ending date).

Under this requirement, `vlue3` will be drop since all its values in `2021-11` are `NaN`s. Other columns have `NaN`s in `2021-11` but not all, so those columns will be kept.

How could I achieve that in Pandas? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])  
mask = (df['date'] >= '2021-11-01') & (df['date'] <= '2021-11-30')
df.loc[mask]
```

Out:

```
         date  value1  value2  value3
8  2021-11-01   1.015     NaN     NaN
9  2021-11-02   1.015  1.0201     NaN
10 2021-11-03     NaN  1.0100     NaN
11 2021-11-30   1.015  1.0000     NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter rows by `November of 2021` and test if all rows has `NaN`s by conditions:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.loc[:, ~df[df['date'].dt.to_period('m') == pd.Period('2021-11')].isna().all()]
```

Or:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.loc[:, df[df['date'].dt.to_period('m') == pd.Period('2021-11')].notna().any()]
```

EDIT: If need manually set some columns for not processing use:

```
mask = (df['date'] >= '2021-11-01') & (df['date'] <= '2021-11-30')
df = df.loc[:, df.loc[mask].notna().any()]
```

Out:

```
         date  value1    value2
0  2021-10-12   1.015  1.115668
1  2021-10-13     NaN  1.104622
2  2021-10-14     NaN  1.093685
3  2021-10-15   1.015  1.082857
4  2021-10-16   1.015  1.072135
5  2021-10-29   1.015  1.061520
6  2021-10-30   1.015  1.051010
7  2021-10-31   1.015       NaN
8  2021-11-01   1.015       NaN
9  2021-11-02   1.015  1.020100
10 2021-11-03     NaN  1.010000
11 2021-11-30   1.015  1.000000
```

EDIT:

```
df = df.assign(value4 = np.nan)
print (df)
          date  value1    value2    value3  value4
0   2021-10-12   1.015  1.115668  1.015000     NaN
1   2021-10-13     NaN  1.104622  1.030225     NaN
2   2021-10-14     NaN  1.093685       NaN     NaN
3   2021-10-15   1.015  1.082857       NaN     NaN
4   2021-10-16   1.015  1.072135  1.077284     NaN
5   2021-10-29   1.015  1.061520  1.093443     NaN
6   2021-10-30   1.015  1.051010  1.109845     NaN
7   2021-10-31   1.015       NaN  1.126493     NaN
8    2021-11-1   1.015       NaN       NaN     NaN
9    2021-11-2   1.015  1.020100       NaN     NaN
10   2021-11-3     NaN  1.010000       NaN     NaN
11  2021-11-30   1.015  1.000000       NaN     NaN
```

---

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

m = df[df['date'].dt.to_period('m') == pd.Period('2021-11')].isna().all()
m.loc['value4'] = False

print (m)
date      False
value1    False
value2    False
value3     True
value4    False
dtype: bool

df = df.loc[:, ~m]
print (df)
         date  value1    value2  value4
0  2021-10-12   1.015  1.115668     NaN
1  2021-10-13     NaN  1.104622     NaN
2  2021-10-14     NaN  1.093685     NaN
3  2021-10-15   1.015  1.082857     NaN
4  2021-10-16   1.015  1.072135     NaN
5  2021-10-29   1.015  1.061520     NaN
6  2021-10-30   1.015  1.051010     NaN
7  2021-10-31   1.015       NaN     NaN
8  2021-11-01   1.015       NaN     NaN
9  2021-11-02   1.015  1.020100     NaN
10 2021-11-03     NaN  1.010000     NaN
11 2021-11-30   1.015  1.000000     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, I added a chunk of code to loc `2021-11` in the question, is it useful?

Comment: I tested all your three methods, all of them works perfectly. :)

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question, if I have a special column `value4`, even the requirement was met, I will keep it anyway. How could I do that?